# NoClassDefFoundError while setting up cucumber tests

Tags: java, cucumber-jvm

I am getting the following error with my cucumber setup. I was following a youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pD4B839qfos&list=PL_noPv5wmuO_t6yYbPfjwhJFOOcio89tI) for this setup but I downloaded all the latest jars. Not sure what went wrong but now I can't figure out what needs to be done. Can anyone help me, please?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/formatter/Formatter
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory$1.<init>(PluginFactory.java:53)
at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.<clinit>(PluginFactory.java:52)
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:69)
at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:31)
at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gherkin.formatter.Formatter
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 17 more
```

Comment: Same unanswered question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32319920/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-gherkin-formatter-for

Comment: Also, there's a comment on the youtube video: "Adding in cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.3.jar solved this issue"

Comment: i already have cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.5.jar added in my libraries and its still causing the issue. I'll see if solves the issue if I downgrade it 1.0.3

Comment: @blank : That didn't solve the issue.

Comment: ok, then you should look in the jar for that class, if it is there, then you might have some problem with your classpath

Comment: some of my jars were incompatible with each other hence the issue  had surfaced. I had downloaded latest jars. When I downgraded the gherkin jar, it worked. Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 2):

This means that Gherkin version you are using is not compatible with other Cucumber libraries. I tried using the latest gherkin3-3.0.0  but it did not work for me, so I degraded it to gherkin-2.12.2

I got below versions on Oct’17 for Cucumber

- cobertura-2.1.1
- cucumber-core-1.2.5
- cucumber-java-1.2.5
- cucumber-junit-1.2.5 cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.5
- cucumber-reporting-3.10.0 gherkin-2.12.2 junit-4.12
- mockito-all-2.0.2-beta

The compatible version with your Cucumber-java can be found [***here***](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java/1.2.5) under the ***Provided Dependencies*** section

If this does not resolve your issue make sure you remove jars from Project Build Path and add back again. Same if you are using maven then clearing local maven repository may also help.

You can also follow the steps mention in this [***tutorial***](http://toolsqa.com/cucumber/download-cucumber-jvm-eclipse/)